# how to add whatever value is selected to an array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, autocomplete, material-ui

I have this Autocomplete :

```
var arr=[];
    const changeHandler = (value) => {
      
        // arr.push(value);
        // console.log("arr",arr)
        setItem(arr)
      };
         <Autocomplete
                getOptionLabel={props.getOptionLabel}
                options={options}
                autoHighlight
                onChange={changeHandler}
                renderOption={(option) => (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    {option.persianCode} - {option.title}
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
                label={props.label}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                inputLabelClassName={classes.instrumentLabel}
              />
```

And I want to add whatever value is selected to an array...I push but every time the value I select is added to it.And the previous value is deleted.Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though `var arr=[];` is in the function body, so it's redeclared each render cycle. Pushing into it will only ever have the one value.

If you want to update the state then use a functional state updated to append a new value.

```
const changeHandler = (value) => {
  setItem(items => [...items, value]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you push to a state variable which is an array, you are not changing the actual object, and react doesn't re-render. [Read more](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove)

What you need to do is, make a deep copy and make the changes on that copy:

```
const changeHandler = value => setItem(arr => [...arr, value])
```